# Hosting multiple socks proxies on a single server

Tags: ip, windows-server-2012, dedicated-server, nic, socks

I have multiple public IP addresses assigned to a single NIC in a Windows Server 2012.

I want to be able to use each IP as a socks proxy server which has to be accessible from other Internet users. How can I do this?

Can a single socks proxy server software be able to host multiple IPs? Do I need to install a virtual server for each IP?
What is the maximum IP addresses I can use like this in a single server/NIC?

Say I have the following public IP addresses:

```
212.216.34.1
212.216.34.2
212.216.34.3
212.216.34.4
...
212.216.34.255
```

What I want is the internet user to be able to connect to internet over any of the above IP addresses like:

```
212.216.34.1:1234
212.216.34.2:1234
212.216.34.3:1234
212.216.34.4:1234
etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your socks proxy to listen on a list of IP addresses or 0.0.0.0 (which means all IPs).

It'll work just fine.

You can also configure different instances of the proxy that behave differently or have different configurations on each IP.